# Reduce not removing correct array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, reactjs, underscore.js

**Edit 1**

Shortened the code to

```
  removeContentNew(i) {
    var contents = this.state.templateContent;
    contents.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({ templateContent: contents });
  }
```

It might have something to do with this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ templateContent: this.props.template.content });
  }
```

Still removing the wrong one on screen. When I log the state, it does give me the right array though. Maybe something wrong with the map?

--

I'm trying to bug fix this piece of code but I can't seem to find the error.

```
removeContent(i) {
 var $formgroup = false;
 const regex = new RegExp('^content.', 'i'),
       contents = _.reduce(_.keys(this.refs), (memo, k) => {
          if (regex.test(k) && k !== 'content.' + i) {
            var $formgroup = $(this.refs[k]);

            if (this.props.customer.getSetting('wysiwyg_enabled', true)) {
              var html = CKEDITOR.instances['html_' + i].getData();
            } else {
              var html = $formgroup.find('[name="html"]').val();
            }

            memo.push({
              subject: $formgroup.find('[name="subject"]').val(),
              html: html,
              text: $formgroup.find('[name="text"]').val(),
              language: $formgroup.find('[name="language"]').val()
            });

          }
          return memo;
        }, []);
this.setState({ templateContent: contents });
}
```

`i` is the ID of the item I want to remove from the array `templateContents`. Every time I press the <kbd>remove</kbd> button of one of the items it always seems to delete the last one and ignores the other ones.

I've been doing some testing with the `k` variable and that one might be the cause of the problems, but I am not sure at all.

I'm really quite new to the RegExp way of doing things.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: What do you want your regex to test for? any value that start with content and is followed by any character? Or any value that start with content followed by a dot? I don't think that the second option makes sense because you get the name of the properties in the object, since the dot is an access operator k will not have a dot character

Comment: @Raulucco The regex is obsolete - See edit. I have no idea why regex was used in this case...

Comment: I don't think you enter the if statement because `k` being the name of a property wont have a dot character in it. Try to check if `k === 'content' && _.isObject(this.refs[k]) && ~_.isUndefined(this.refs[k][i])`

Comment: you can use `!_.isNull(_.get(this.refs, [k, i], null))`, i think is more readable

Comment: @Raulucco Splice will do the same thing though. I think I'm going to use the splice because of the amount of code it needs. Do you have any idea why the state is updating correctly but my array.map isn't? It just keeps deleting the last one instead of the one I removed from the array.

Comment: @JorenPolfliet Deleting the last item of the array means that `splice()` is getting either the last item, or -1. What do you mean that the state is updating correctly but array.map isn't? where are you using array.map? and check the parameter `i` you're sending to the function.

Comment: @MamdohSaraireh I'll give you an easy example. the array is [ 1,2,3 ]. When I delete 2 and I log the state, it says [ 1,3 ], but on my screen it shows 1 and 2, while two is the one I removed. I think it might have something to do with the state being props at the start.

Comment: @JorenPolfliet Anyway i think that instead of updating the state in the componentDidMount() method do it on the contructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the mapping of the array. I'll leave this here because it helped me solve my issue.

> Bad (Usually)

```
<tbody>
    {rows.map((row, i) => {
        return <ObjectRow key={i} />;
    })}
</tbody>
```

> This is arguably the most common mistake seen when iterating over an
>   array in React. This approach will work fine unless an element is
>   added or removed from the rows array. If you are iterating through
>   something that is static, then this is perfectly valid (e.g an array
>   of links in your navigation menu). Take a look at this detailed
>   explanation on the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Update your state in the `constructor` instead of inside `componentDidMount` method.

```
constructor(pops) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    templateContent: this.props.template.content
  }
}
```

Also calls to setState are async so you don't have any security when the changes is being executed